# VBA in Word: Programmatically add content control with a style

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

When programatically adding a rich text content control to a Word .docm using VBA, is there a way to set a style for the contents?

As a comparison, if I create a content control manually using the Word Developer toolbar, I can select "Use a style to format contents" in the properties dialog for the content control. The result I want is the same as if I did it that way, except I need to do it in code.

Here's the code I have that adds the content control, it's triggered by a command button click that does a few other things as well:

```
Private Sub selConcept_Click()

    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(3).Delete
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(3).Delete

    Dim oCC As ContentControl
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, _
              Selection.Range)
    oCC.SetPlaceholderText , , "My placeholder text is here."
    oCC.Title = "Concept"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you record a macro when you are applying the formatting you want, you can then look at the vba module that the macro recorder created and that will show you the code you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already created the style, you can just assign it like this:

```
oCC.DefaultTextStyle = "style_name"
```

Now, if not, you'll have to add your *style* first. Something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles.Add Name:="MyStyle1", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter
With ActiveDocument.Styles("MyStyle1").Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 12
    .Bold = True
    .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'you can use RGB here
End With

oCC.DefaultTextStyle = "MyStyle1"
```

Comment: Great. I can use a style I added to the document already but it's good to know how to add the style also, I tried both ways and it works, I might end doing it by adding the style, that might be better for various reasons. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @user3762977 Np and yeah adding your style is ok. But take note that if the style already exist, it will generate an error. So make sure to add an error handler or iterate through existing styles first if it already exist before adding it.