# Word- VBA- Why do I get a Run Time Error 451 "Property Let Procedure Not Defined And Property Get Procedure Did Not Return Object"?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code successfully works despite giving me a Run Time Error 451 "Property Let Procedure Not Defined And Property Get Procedure Did Not Return Object".

Debugger flags `With oCC.Range.Style("Placeholder Text").Font` as the culprit.

I need to apply a style to the placeholder text so that it doesn't reset when values are entered or deleted.

What is missing?

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim ocell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, ocell.Range)
    With oCC
        .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1"
        .Tag = "Test1"
        .Setplaceholdertext , , "test1"
        If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
             With oCC.Range.Style("Placeholder Text").Font
                                    
                   .Name = "Arial"
                   .Size = 8
                   .ColorIndex = wdRed
                   .Italic = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `With oCC.Range.Font`? A guess.

Comment: No, I need to apply style to the placeholder text so that it doesn't reset to default style

Comment: [Seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162374/how-do-i-change-a-microsoft-word-content-control-placeholder-text-format-using-a)

Comment: ```With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font``` works but it sets the style for the entire document not just the one cell.  I want to have different placeholder text styles throughout the document

Comment: You either have to apply a new style to oCC.Range  or set a font property of oCC range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out somehow.

Using `With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font` below sets placeholder text framework for the whole document and prevents from resetting.

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim ocell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, ocell.Range)
    With oCC
        .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1"
        .Tag = "Test1"
        .Setplaceholdertext , , "test1"
        If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
             **With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font**       
                   .Name = "Arial"
                   .Size = 8
                   .ColorIndex = wdRed
                   .Italic = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
```

Then, in my case, for each subsequent placeholder text within the document, I can then modify their formatting, respectively, using `With oCC.Range.Font` as seen below.

```
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(2)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, ocell.Range)
    With oCC
        .DefaultTextStyle = "Style2"
        .Tag = "test2"
        .SetPlaceholderText , , "test2"
        If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
            **With oCC.Range.Font**
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 12
                .ColorIndex = wdBlack
                .Italic = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

“I need to apply a style to the placeholder text so that it doesn't reset when values are entered or deleted.“

That isn’t how ContentControls work. As has been explained to you before, placeholder text is temporary by design. You can apply formatting to it whilst it is there but as soon as the text is gone so is the formatting you applied to it.

If the text that replaced the placeholder text is deleted the default formatting, the style 'Placeholder Text', will then apply to any placeholder text that the content control displays afterwards.

If having different formatting is vital to your project your only option would be to create a `ContentControlOnExit` event in the `ThisDocument` module which would need to check whether the exited content control was showing placeholder text and then apply the appropriate formatting. This will require you to find some method of identifying which formatting should apply to the content control.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this isn't possible with VBA. The object model doesn't include a method to set the placeholder style. Here is the XML of an unmodified Rich Text content control:

```
<w:sdtContent>
    <w:p w14:paraId="13211677" w14:textId="4A21E55A" w:rsidR="00A934F5" w:rsidRDefault="00EB0426" w:rsidP="00857546">
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00FD3EE5">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Click or tap here to enter text.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:sdtContent>
```

At first I thought you could create a custom style, then apply that with VBA:

```
oCC.Range.Style = "PlaceholderText1"
```

But that changes only the appearance of entered text, not the placeholder text. This is identical to setting the style in the content control Properties dialog. Here's the XML after running that:

```
<w:sdtContent>
    <w:p w14:paraId="0686A900" w14:textId="2CAB6B2E" w:rsidR="00A934F5" w:rsidRPr="00332D6D" w:rsidRDefault="00332D6D" w:rsidP="00332D6D">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="PlaceholderText1"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00D90D77">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Click or tap here to enter text.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:sdtContent>
```

The style has been added, but the placeholder style has not changed. When you type text, the text appears in the style set by the macro.

To work around this, create several alternate placeholder text styles. (Hint: don't use spaces in these style names). Then create the same number of content controls. Open the file to edit the XML and replace the "PlaceHolderText" name with the name of a new style in each content control.

Then open the document and save each content control as AutoText/Building Blocks. Then use VBA to insert those styled content controls:

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("CCStyle1").Insert Where:=oCell.Range, RichText:=True
```

Here's my article about editing OOXML: [OOXML Hacking: An Introduction](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/02/xml-hacking-an-introduction/)